# GCP write only access to bucket (GCS)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket

We are trying to create different bucket for different source system, and give them access only to dump data on particular bucket. They should not have read access, i.e. they shouldnt  be able to see hats there inside the bucket. Is it doable , if yes how ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have a bucket that only allows new files to be added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44532902/is-it-possible-to-have-a-bucket-that-only-allows-new-files-to-be-added)

Answer (score 6):

You are probably looking for `roles/storage.objectCreator` role (take a look at [IAM roles for Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles)) :

> Allows users to create objects. Does not give permission to view, delete, or overwrite objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) for your project, which has only write access. Find storage permissions [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles). Then you can assign the created custom role to a person or service account with IAM.